# Using parameter sent by HTML in views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a DB Emp with following data:

```
id|name|project
1|tom|p01
2|tom|p02
3|tom|p03
4|mat|p04
5|mat|p05
6|katie|p06
```

I display the distinct Emp.name in an html page name.html as below:

```
<a href="emp/{{ Emp.name }}/project/">{{ Emp.name }}</a>
```

Now when the user selects a perticular Emp.name, I want to display all the project values for that name in a new html page project.html. So I need to write the view as below:

```
def project(request, ***emp_name***):
    proj_list = Emp.objects.filter(name=***emp_name***)
    t = loader.get_template('name/project.html')
    c = Context({
        'proj_list': proj_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

name.html has to return emp_name to the view project() in order to query the DB. How to pass emp_name and how to use it in project()?

Comment: I would highly suggest working through the tutorials on the Django site, as this is a very, very basic principal in Django.

Answer (score 0):

From `urls.py`, you can extract the `emp_name` and pass it to the view. You have to use `named-groups`. For more details, refer 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a URL pattern that will pass the parameter to the view:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url, patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('your_module.views',
    url(r'^emp/(?P<emp_name>\w+)/project/$', 'project', name='projects'),
)
```

Then you need to refactor your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from your_module.models import Emp

def project(request, emp_name):
    proj_list = Emp.objects.filter(name=emp_name)
    return render(request, 'name/project.html', {'proj_list': proj_list})
```